# ArrayList not Iterating in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a Spring Boot project that uses `Google Maps JavaScript API` and `Google Places API` to retrieve trail information based on location. I am trying to display a list of events as well as the list of trails on the map, as both have a location. The EventDTO class is as follows:

```
package com.trailfinder.dto;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Transient;

/**
 * @author LookItsCashew
 * DTO for Events posted on application
 */
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
@Table(name="events")
public class EventDTO implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name="EventID")
    private int eventId;
    @Column(name="Distance")
    private double distance;
    @Column(name="EventStart")
    private LocalDateTime eventStart;
    @Column(name="EventEnd")
    private LocalDateTime eventEnd;
    @Column(name="Latitude")
    private String Latitude;
    @Column(name="Longitude")
    private String Longitude;
    @Transient
    private EventCreatorDTO eventCreator;

    /**
     * Create and initialize a new instance of the EventDTO
     * 
     * @param eventId
     * @param distance
     * @param eventStart
     * @param eventEnd
     * @param latitude
     * @param longitude
     * @param eventCreator
     */
    public EventDTO(double distance, LocalDateTime eventStart, LocalDateTime eventEnd, String latitude, 
            String longitude, EventCreatorDTO eventCreator) 
    {
        this.distance = distance;
        this.eventStart = eventStart;
        this.eventEnd = eventEnd;
        this.Latitude = latitude;
        this.Longitude = longitude;
        this.eventCreator = eventCreator;
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of EventDTO
     */
    public EventDTO() {

    }

    /**
     * @return the eventId
     */
    public int getEventId() {
        return eventId;
    }

    /**
     * @param eventId the eventId to set
     */
    public void setEventId(int eventId) {
        this.eventId = eventId;
    }

    /**
     * @return the distance
     */
    public double getDistance() {
        return distance;
    }

    /**
     * @param distance the distance to set
     */
    public void setDistance(double distance) {
        this.distance = distance;
    }

    /**
     * @return the eventStart
     */
    public LocalDateTime getEventStart() {
        return eventStart;
    }

    /**
     * @param eventStart the eventStart to set
     */
    public void setEventStart(LocalDateTime eventStart) {
        this.eventStart = eventStart;
    }

    /**
     * @return the eventEnd
     */
    public LocalDateTime getEventEnd() {
        return eventEnd;
    }

    /**
     * @param eventEnd the eventEnd to set
     */
    public void setEventEnd(LocalDateTime eventEnd) {
        this.eventEnd = eventEnd;
    }

    /**
     * @return the latitude
     */
    public String getLatitude() {
        return Latitude;
    }

    /**
     * @param latitude the latitude to set
     */
    public void setLatitude(String latitude) {
        Latitude = latitude;
    }

    /**
     * @return the longitude
     */
    public String getLongitude() {
        return Longitude;
    }

    /**
     * @param longitude the longitude to set
     */
    public void setLongitude(String longitude) {
        Longitude = longitude;
    }

    /**
     * @return the eventCreator
     */
    public EventCreatorDTO getEventCreator() {
        return eventCreator;
    }

    /**
     * @param eventCreator the eventCreator to set
     */
    public void setEventCreator(EventCreatorDTO eventCreator) {
        this.eventCreator = eventCreator;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return eventCreator.getCreatorFirstName() + "'s hiking event";
    }
}
```

And my TrailDTO is like so:

```
package com.trailfinder.dto;

/**
 * @author LookItsCashew
 * Represents a trail Place that is nearby from Google Places library
 * Will be separate entities from Events, which are user created and custom
 */
public class TrailDTO {

    // Private fields
    private String id;
    private String placeId;
    private String name;
    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;
    //Adds an interesting bit to the trail
    private String hotSpot;



    /**
     * @return the id
     */
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    /**
     * @param id the id to set
     */
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    /**
     * @return the placeId
     */
    public String getPlaceId() {
        return placeId;
    }
    /**
     * @param placeId the placeId to set
     */
    public void setPlaceId(String placeId) {
        this.placeId = placeId;
    }
    /**
     * @return the name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    /**
     * @param name the name to set
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    /**
     * @return the latitude
     */
    public double getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }
    /**
     * @param latitude the latitude to set
     */
    public void setLatitude(double latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }
    /**
     * @return the longitude
     */
    public double getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }
    /**
     * @param longitude the longitude to set
     */
    public void setLongitude(double longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }
    public String gethotSpot(){
        return hotSpot;
    }
    public String sedhotSpot(String hotSpot){
        return hotSpot;
    }


}
```

My index page is where the map lives and uses `JQuery` to request a `List` of trails and events from the controller as `JSON`, which would then be iterated over and markers created where the `TrailDTO`locations are, and same for the events. My controller passes a `List` of either trails or events and only the trails are showing up on the map. Here is my `Controller`:

```
package com.trailfinder;



import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import com.trailfinder.dto.EventAttendeeDTO;
import com.trailfinder.dto.EventDTO;
import com.trailfinder.dto.TrailDTO;
import com.trailfinder.service.IHikeService;

/**
 * @author LookItsCashew
 * Controller for the TrailFinder UI layer
 */

@Controller
public class TrailFinderController {

    @Autowired
    private IHikeService hikeService;

    /**
     * Handles return of home screen view and index end point
     * @return index
     */
    @RequestMapping("/index")
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }

    /**
     * Handles return of home screen view and / end point
     * @return index
     * @throws Exception 
     */
    @RequestMapping(value="/", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String base(Model model) {
        Iterable<EventDTO> events = null;
        try {
            events = hikeService.getEvents();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        model.addAttribute("events", events);
        return "index";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/Event", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String evt(@RequestParam(value="eventId") int eventId, Model model) {
        EventDTO eventDTO;
        List<EventAttendeeDTO> attendees=null;
        try {
            eventDTO = hikeService.fetchEventById(eventId);
            attendees = hikeService.getAttendees(eventDTO);
            model.addAttribute("event", eventDTO);
            model.addAttribute("attendees", attendees);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return "eventdetails";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/Event/Attend", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String attendEvent(@RequestParam(value="eventId", required=true) int eventId, EventAttendeeDTO attendee, Model model) {
        boolean isEventAttended;
        try {
            // fetch the event user is attending
            EventDTO eventAttending = hikeService.fetchEventById(attendee.getEventId());
            attendee.setEvent(eventAttending);

            // Persist the attendee
            isEventAttended = hikeService.attendEvent(attendee);
            if (isEventAttended) {
                model.addAttribute("event", eventAttending);
                return "eventdetails";
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "index";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/profile", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String prof(Model model) {
        //ProfileDTO profile = hikeService.getProfile(0);
        //model.addAttribute("ProfileDTO", profile);
        return "profile";
    }

    /**
     * Needs to return the JSON of all trails from Google Places
     * @param lat the latitiude of the user's current location
     * @param lng the longitude of the user's current location
     * @return trails the trails to be returned to the view
     */
    @RequestMapping(value="/fetchTrailList", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
    @ResponseBody
    public List<TrailDTO> fetchTrailList(@RequestParam(value="lat") double lat, @RequestParam(value="lng") double lng) {
        // List of trails to return 
        List<TrailDTO> trails = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            trails = hikeService.getNearbyTrails(lat, lng);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return trails;
    }

    /**
     * Needs to return the JSON of all events from persistence
     * @return events the events to be returned to the view
     */
    @RequestMapping(value="/getEventsJSON", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
    @ResponseBody
    public List<EventDTO> getEventsJSON() {
        // List of trails to return 
        List<EventDTO> events = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            events = (List<EventDTO>) hikeService.getEvents();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return events;
    }

}
```

Here is my `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1"/>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<style>
       /* Set the size of the div element that contains the map */
      #map {
        height: 400px;  /* The height is 400 pixels */
        width: 100%;  /* The width is the width of the web page */
       }
    </style>

<title>TrailFinder | Home</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main" class="container">
        <div th:replace = "fragments/headbar :: navbar"></div>
        <br>
        <div id="content">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                    <div id="map" class="container container-fluid">

                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                <h3>Events Near You</h3>
                    <!--list event attributes here -->
                    <div class="list-group list-group-action" th:each="event : ${events}">
                    <a th:href="@{/Event(eventId=${event.eventId})}" class="list-group-item">
                    <p th:text="${event}"/>
                    </a>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
     function initMap() {
         var map;
         var trailMarker = {
                  path: 'M0-48c-9.8 0-17.7 7.8-17.7 17.4 0 15.5 17.7 30.6 17.7 30.6s17.7-15.4 17.7-30.6c0-9.6-7.9-17.4-17.7-17.4z',
                  fillColor: '#019730',
                  fillOpacity: 0.95,
                  scale: 0.8,
                  strokeColor: '#01AD37',
                  strokeWeight: 0.5
                };
            //Geolocation
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
              navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                var pos = {
                  lat: position.coords.latitude,
                  lng: position.coords.longitude
                };

              // Map options
              var options = {
                      zoom:12,
                      center:pos
              }
              // The map, centered at current location
              map = new google.maps.Map(
                  document.getElementById('map'), options);

              var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

                infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
                infoWindow.setContent('You are here!');
                infoWindow.open(map);
                //map.setCenter(pos); // center map to user cordinates
                // Creates trails in map
                createTrails(pos);

              }, function() {
                handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
              });


            } else {
              // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
              handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
            }

            createEventsInMap();

          function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
            infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
            infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
                                  'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
                                  'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
            infoWindow.open(map);

            } 
          function createTrails(pos) {
             $.getJSON("/fetchTrailList", { lat: pos.lat, lng: pos.lng }, function (data) {
                 $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                    //console.log(data[key]);
                    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: {lat: value.latitude, lng: value.longitude}, map: map, icon: trailMarker});
                    infoWindow.setPosition({ lat: value.latitude, lng: value.longitude });
                    infoWindow.setContent('<h3>' + value.name + '</h3>' + '<p>Coords: ' + value.latitude + ', '
                    + value.longitude + '</p>' + '<a href="#"><p>Create Event...</p></a>');
                    marker.addListener('click', function() {
                        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                    });
                 });
             });
            }

          function createEventsInMap() {
              $.getJSON("/getEventsJSON", function (data) {
                     $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                        console.log(data[key]);
                        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: {lat: value.Latitude, lng: value.Longitude}, map: map});
                        infoWindow.setPosition({ lat: value.Latitude, lng: value.Longitude });
                        infoWindow.setContent('<h3>' + value.eventCreator.creatorFirstName + '</h3>' 
                                + '<p>Distance: ' + value.distance + ' km' + '</p>' + '<a href="@{/Event(eventId=' + value.eventId + '}"><p>View Event</p></a>');
                        marker.addListener('click', function() {
                            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                        });
                     }); 
                  });

          }

         }


    </script> 
    <script async="true" defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCmC6Uco6nl8sRYwKBa8Xnjll3olfbYGKM&callback=initMap">
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Both functions for returning `JSON` are almost identical in structure, but send different types of `Lists` back to the `index.html` page. Not sure why one list type works but the other does not? Any answers or assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: **javascript** does not have `ArrayList` as a class.  That's a **java** class.

Comment: Also, you said one type works and one type does not.  Which one is not working?

Comment: @Taplar the `List<TrailDTO>` that is returned from the `controller` when the index page calls `/fetchTrailList`

Comment: My point is once it reaches the client, it's not that class anymore.  It has been turned into JSON, and once it is parsed by javascript, it is simply composed of arrays and objects.  The frontend has no knowledge of that java class.

Comment: @Taplar I have resolved. When testing, it appeared there was an issue converting a list of `EventDTOs` to `JSON` because of an "Illegal Recursive Function" or something to that effect. It does make sense, as an `EventDTO` has an `EventCreatorDTO` field, and that class has a field for the creator's event. I resolved this by making a new `Event` class that's the same as my `EventDTO` but does not use Spring's persistence annotations. Instead, it represents an `EventDTO` as a simple object. The `getEventsJSON` endpoint now returns a `JSON` list of `Events` rather than trying to use the `EventDTO`